# How to write dynamic json to bigquery? is bigquery even a right tool for this?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

My data source is based on the events happening in the 3rd party tool. eg: - customer.created, customer.updated, customer.plan.updated. Every event has different json schema. And it is possible even the same event eg: customer.updated may have different schema from previous customer.updated event. I am planning to load this data in BigQuery but it appears that BigQuery doesn't support dynamic schema. I am building a data warehouse and want to store all the events related to customer in same table. Is bigquery a right tool for such data? Are there other better options in GCP bigtable/cloud datastore/cloud sql etc. for such type of data? One of the requirement is that, if possible, the data can be queried easily by non-technical people who can do simple select,join queries.

Comment: same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45037415/how-to-create-a-table-in-bigquery-using-python-when-schema-keeps-changing/45043616#45043616?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a table in Bigquery using Python when schema keeps changing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45037415/how-to-create-a-table-in-bigquery-using-python-when-schema-keeps-changing)