# How to create a table in Bigquery using Python when schema keeps changing?

Tags: google-bigquery

My data source is based on the events happening in the 3rd party tool. eg: - `customer.created`, `customer.updated`, `customer.plan.updated`. Every event has different `json` schema. And it is possible even the same event eg: `customer.updated` may have different schema from previous `customer.updated` event.

I am planning to load this data into `BigQuery` but it appears that `BigQuery` doesn't support dynamic schema. I am building a data warehouse and want to store all the events related to customer in same table.

Is `bigquery` a right tool for such data? Are there other better options in GCP bigtable/cloud datastore/cloud sql etc. for such type of data? One of the requirement is that, if possible, the data can be queried easily by non-technical people who can do simple `select`,`join` queries.

Comment: Do any of the schemas have incompatible types? For example, does one event have `customer.id` that's a string and another event has `customer.id` that's an integer? If they are all compatible, you could include all the event types in a large schema. This is similar to what the [LogEntry](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/using_exported_logs#schemas_and_fields) and [AuditData](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs) tables do.

Comment: No, the type will be same. What is "large schema"? Do you mean stick the whole json into one cell in bigquery table?

Answer (score 3):

You'll get the best results in BigQuery when you can put your data in well defined columns, but you will also get great results if you just store JSON objects stored as strings.

For example, see how https://www.githubarchive.org/ does it:

- GitHub Archive stores many types of GitHub events. Most of them have the same set of properties - so we can store them in pre-defined columns.
- Some GitHub events schemas are different for each type of event, and they also keep changing through time. Instead of dealing with schema changes, we just store them as JSON strings and we query them in real time.

[image]

```
#standardSQL
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, '$.pull_request.base.repo.language') lang
  , COUNT(*) c 
FROM `githubarchive.month.201612`
WHERE type='PullRequestEvent'
GROUP BY lang 
HAVING lang IS NOT null
ORDER BY c DESC
LIMIT 10
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know how I can dump the full json object in one column? My json looks like this `{"data":{"type":"notification_event_data","item":{"type":"user","id":"xxxxxxxx","user_id":null,"anonymous":false,"email":"ma8151-` When I do `table.insert_data(json.loads(data))` I am only getting `{` in the table. Somehow the whole json is not being inserted into the table column.

Comment: Are you streaming data in for a reason, or would batch work for you?

Comment: It's a business requirement. And why would that matter? The data will still be same if I pull the "events" via API.

Comment: Just wondering if you would consider an alternative to `table.insert_data()`

Comment: JSON needs to be newline delimited... E.g. one JSON record per line. So check if there is a newline following the open curly brace.